# Why we need both mutexes and semaphores?

Tags: mutex, semaphore

Semaphore can replace a mutex:

1. initialize sem with 1
2. lock(): do sem_wait(); (in critical section sem = 0)
3. unlock(): do sem_post(1);

Then why we need mutex?

Answer (score 0):

Mutex exists mainly to guard a critical section of a code. When compared to semaphore, it can have better performance than semaphore due to code being simpler and shorter or it can provide richer functionality.

There are many types of mutexes: "normal" mutex, recursive mutex, shared mutex (reader-writer lock). Some mutex implementations can try to implement "priority inheritence" to battle priority inversion. All of this cannot be implemented for semaphore, because its usage pattern is too broad.